# Custom browser won't render what's served by custom web server

Tags: tcl, client-server

I've modified the Tatu web server to run on a random port and return this value from it's startServer proc.  Then I am launching a custom browser (deskmlviewer) pointed at `"http://localhost:$port"` as follows:

```
set port [tatu::startServer "" "" $tatu::options]

set deskmlRunner {
    set viewer [file join $::starkit::topdir .. .. gui bin deskmlviewer.exe]
    #puts "$viewer http://localhost:$port"
    exec $viewer "http://localhost:$port"
}

after 1 $deskmlRunner
vwait forever
```

All this does though is launch the browser *without rendering the content*.  However this is what the commented out `puts` line output on one of my runs:

```
C:/opt/dev/dexygen/github/repos/deskml/deskml-win/srv/tatuDeskml.vfs/../../gui/bin/deskmlviewer.exe http://localhost:56077
```

I was then able to run this from the console and the browser displayed the content rendered by the server; also I could likewise take `http://localhost:56077` and run it in Chrome and it would render the expected content.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2VIm.png

I tried increasing the `ms` argument to `after` including all the way up to something absurd like 5000 but this had no effect.  Also I tried surrounding all or part of the url argument to `$viewer` with curly braces in case the slashes were being converted to lean the other way, but this too had no effect.

What am I doing wrong?  What else can I try?  You can even try for yourself by cloning the git repo at https://github.com/dexygen/deskml and navigating to deskml-win and running `./tclkitsh ./srv/tatuDeskml.vfs/main.tcl`; the code above resides in `./deskml-win/srv/lib/app/deskml-runner.tcl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer entails putting an & at the end of the exec command

```
exec $viewer "http://localhost:$port" &
```

Because otherwise it was synchronous and blocking.  The credit does not belong to me but to the following user/response on usenet

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.tcl/YOK8a2i0bk8/Qw-12Pn8AgAJ